# React Native Firebase Phone Auth - phoneAuthSnapshot has NULL values for verificationId and code

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am trying to use react-native-firebase to do Phone Auth. Firebase is correctly set-up. I can get SMS code back for some phone numbers. I am using verifyPhoneNumber method. My code looks like this:

```
firebase
      .auth()
      .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .on('state_changed', phoneAuthSnapshot => {
        console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot);
        switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
```

phoneAuthSnapshot contains below:

```
{verificationId: null, code: null, error: null, state: "verified"}
```

Now, since both verificationId and code are NULL, I cannot build credentials:

```
const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
  verificationId,
  codeInput
);
```

Since, I cannot build credentials, I cannot get the user details:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithCredential(credential)
  .then(user => {
    console.log('PHONE AUTH USER ->>>>>', user.toJSON());
    this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
  })
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have a similar problem of getting null in the verificationId property

Comment: are you solve it ?